# JavaFX: Stage in Controller - best solution

Tags: java, javafx-2

I need the current Stage in my Controller ans after searching I found two solutions:

1. Pass the Stage to my Controller at initializing (like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247005/2039619))
2. Get it from a controll (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003426/2039619)

What is the best solution?

Comment: I think this question is not more opinion-based than other ones.

I asked this, because I wanted experiens from other. How the do it. I think, that's the purpose of this site too.

And I got one very helpfull answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the stage from the FXML controller can be tricky, as if it has not finished loading, you cannot access to the scene through the components (in your FXML) thus to the stage (null pointer!). You'll have to add code in initialize method (from Initializable interface) to get safely the current stage at runtime from any component declared in your controller.

The other choice seems for me better, as you can do stuff with the stage ASAP, which also means before the rendering of the current FXML, as you insert the stage explicitely into the controller (with a setter, you add a reference to it), you don't need to wait for GUI stuff in your current FXML. The disadvantage is that you need to add explicit code for delivering the stage to your FXML controllers (and from controllers to controllers, etc).