# Is there any way to access FXML variables in classes other than Controller Class?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I'm curious that is there any way to call @FXML variables in not only Controller Class but also in another classes. Well actually i'm dealing with `SVGPath` nodes and trying to implement various kind graphs. However i dont wanna write the whole code in only Controller Class. I will appreciate if you can help and also give clear answers. So thanks anyway :)

EDIT: let me introduce a simple example about my issue.

Controller class code section;

```
public class RiskControllerClass implements Initializable {

   @FXML private SVGPath NA_1; // Alaska
   @FXML private SVGPath NA_2; // NorthWest_Ter
   .
   .
}
```

`Territory` class which refers to a vertex in a graph

```
public class Territory {

    public Territory(SVGPath nodeSVG, int territoryID, int playerID){

        this.playerID = playerID;
        this.territoryID = territoryID;
        this.nodeSVG = nodeSVG;
        this.label = nodeSVG.getId();
        this.adjacencyList = new LinkedList<>();
        this.edgeSet = new LinkedList<>();
    }
.
.
}
```

so i want to implement my graph another class than Controller class something like `GameBoard`

```
public class GameBoard  {

    // Want to call @FXML instance variables here

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other way than to access your controller and call methods from it. There is no magical way an `@FXML` annotation makes private variables globally available. `@FXML` is only used to mark certain fields for the `FXMLLoader` so he can access them via reflection in the instantiation process of your FXML - nothing else.

Refere to this questions on how to access the controller:

[Accessing FXML controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class?rq=1)

[JavaFX: How to get stage from controller during initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246211/javafx-how-to-get-stage-from-controller-during-initialization/13247005#13247005)