# Dragging an undecorated Stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to have a Stage set to "UNDECORATED" made draggable and minimizable. The problem is that I can't find a way to do so since the examples I come accross that do this do so via methods inserted inside the main method.

I would like to have this done via a method declared in the controller class, like how I managed to do with the "WindowClose()" method below.

This is my second day working with JavaFX, if this seems too much of a common knowledge question. Thank you all in advance.

```
// Main Class/ Method

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Fxmltableview extends Application {

    public static String pageSource = "fxml_tableview.fxml";
    public static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(pageSource));

        scene = new Scene(root, Color.TRANSPARENT);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

..

```
// The Controller

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class FXMLTableViewController {
    @FXML private TableView<Person> tableView;
    @FXML private TextField firstNameField;
    @FXML private TextField lastNameField;
    @FXML private TextField emailField;

    @FXML
    protected void addPerson (ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<Person> data = tableView.getItems();
        data.add(new Person(
                firstNameField.getText(),
                lastNameField.getText(),
                emailField.getText()
                ));

        firstNameField.setText("");
        lastNameField.setText("");
        emailField.setText("");   
    }

    public void WindowClose (ActionEvent event) {
            Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Drag a Stage accross the screen in JAVAFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809324/how-to-drag-a-stage-accross-the-screen-in-javafx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Strategy*

You already have a reference to the stage in your start method.

What you need is to be able to pass the stage to your controller, so that the controller can make the stage draggable by a given node.

1. The "Passing Parameters Directly From the Caller to the Controller" method may be used to pass a stage reference to your controller: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).
2. Use the [makeDraggable method from this sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637) to allow the stage to be dragged by a given node.

*Sample Implementation*

Some psuedo-code for the Application start method follows:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
  getClass().getResource(
    "fxml_tableview.fxml"
  )
);

stage.setScene(
  new Scene(
    (Parent) loader.load()
  )
);

FXMLTableViewController controller = 
  loader.<FXMLTableViewController>getController();
controller.registerStage(stage);

stage.show();
```

And for the Controller's new registerStage method:

```
@FXML private Rectangle dragNode;

public void registerStage(Stage stage) {
  EffectUtilities.makeDraggable(stage, dragNode)
}
```

`EffectUtilities.makeDraggable()` comes from the sample code I linked earlier.

Update your `fxml_tableview.fxml` file to include the required new `dragNode` referenced in the controller.

*Alternate implementation*

In the initialize method of the controller, add a change listener on the dragNode's sceneProperty and the changed scene's window property to get notified of the stage change so that you can invoke makeDraggable.

*Sample Code `EffectUtilities.makeDraggable(stage, byNode)`*

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/** Various utilities for applying different effects to nodes. */
public class EffectUtilities {
  /** makes a stage draggable using a given node */
  public static void makeDraggable(final Stage stage, final Node byNode) {
    final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
    byNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
        dragDelta.x = stage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
        dragDelta.y = stage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
        byNode.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
      }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        byNode.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
      }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
        stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
      }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
          byNode.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        }
      }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
          byNode.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /** records relative x and y co-ordinates. */
  private static class Delta {
    double x, y;
  }
}
```

Comment: i do not know where to get these `EffectUtilities`?!

Comment: Attached a copy of EffectUtilities sample code (it is also [linked in the answer](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637)).

Answer (score 2):

From FXML set the id of your controller or component you want to use to drag your Application

```
    <Pane onMousePressed="#panePressed" onMouseDragged="#paneDragged"/>
```

From class `Controller.java`

```java
    @FXML public void panePressed(MouseEvent me){
        delta.x = getStage().getX() - me.getScreenX();
        delta.y = getStage().getY() - me.getScreenY();
    }

    @FXML public void paneDragged(MouseEvent me){
        getStage().setX(delta.x + me.getScreenX());
        getStage().setY(delta.y + me.getScreenY());
    }
```

You must have delta class which will stored the value of delta x and y

```java
    public class Delta{
        public double x,y;
    }
```

To get the stage just create mutator and accessor, for more information about casting just go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247005/10646511)

Answer (score 0):

Create this Delta class.

```
public class Delta {
    double x,y;
}
```

In controller class , make instance of Delta class and  add these two methods.

```
public void panepressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
     stage = (Stage)((Node)me.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
     delta.x= stage.getX()- me.getScreenX();
     delta.y= stage.getY()- me.getScreenY();


    }
    public void panedraged(MouseEvent me)
    {
     stage = (Stage)((Node)me.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
     stage.setX(delta.x+me.getScreenX());
     stage.setY(delta.y+me.getScreenY());


    }
```

Next add these two methods in your fxml file or scene builder respectively for mousepressed and mousedragged.

```
<AnchorPane  onMouseDragged="#panedraged" onMousePressed="#panepressed" prefHeight="274.0" prefWidth="250.0" />
```