# Bind Font Size in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, data-binding, fonts, javafx

I'd like to make my application fluid. However, the fonts look small compared to the UI elements when I make the windows bigger. Ultimately, I want the size of my text to get bigger or smaller when I resize the window. I know I could theoretically do this with the style property, but I already have that property bound to something else in some instances.

I know there's the "fontProperty" method, but I have nothing to bind it to since I can't figure out how to create a dynamic ObjectProperty with a synced size. What should I do?

EDIT: To avoid confusion, I'm trying to make the Font size change based on other factors, not the other way around.

Answer (score 17):

Just put everything where you want the fontsize to change in a container and set that style or use bindings if you want.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontBind extends Application {

    private DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10);
    private IntegerProperty blues = new SimpleIntegerProperty(50);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button("click me, I change color");
        btn.setOnAction((evt)->{blues.set(blues.get()+20);});//max?
        Label lbl = new Label("I'm a label");
        TextArea ta = new TextArea("Lots of text can be typed\nand even number 1234567890");
        HBox hbox = new HBox(new Label("I never change"));
        VBox child = new VBox(btn, lbl, ta);
        VBox root = new VBox(child, hbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        fontSize.bind(scene.widthProperty().add(scene.heightProperty()).divide(50));
        child.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString(), ";"
                                                  ,"-fx-base: rgb(100,100,",blues.asString(),");"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what your style is already bound to, but you're allowed to set multiple css values in the style string.

Comment: That was what I originally thought to do, but the -fx-styles of some objects are dynamically bound to various other properties. There's no concrete way to detect what it's being bound to, so I can't use this. I doubt the JavaFX people would just create FontProperty of you can do anything substantial with it.

Comment: It doesn't matter, just put everything you want to change the font for in one container.  Notice how everything in the vbox child has the font changed.  You can have layers of containers with different css values.

Comment: Like I said, this is being done dynamically. Are you saying I would have to encase every component I modify in its own container just to apply CSS to it? It seems like an awfully ugly workaround, but if its all I've got, I guess It'll have to do :/.

Comment: No, only if you want different css values for the same element, like having different fonts.  As you can see in my example, I bound 2 unrelated css values to the same style string using concat.  You said your style property is already bound, just add a concat to whatever else you want.

Comment: For me, this does not change child labels font size. Is their a work around for this?

Answer (score 10):

**Set the .root -fx-font-size**

1. Create a [custom stylesheet](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) for your application.
2. In sylesheet `.root` selector, set `-fx-font-size` to your desired value:

   .root {
       -fx-font-size: 40px;
   }

**Why this works**

This works because:

1. All of the default controls are based on [`em`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typelength) units (which are based on the default font size).
2. `-fx-font-size` is an [inherited](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introinheritance) style.
3. Everything inherits from the root.

Once you do this, all controls (and the text inside them) will automatically resize nicely to fit whatever font size you specified.

**Related Sample**

- [javafx automatic resizing and button padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229149/javafx-automatic-resizing-and-button-padding)

**Related Information**

`em` is a generic unit that is not specific to JavaFX and em units are also used in HTML CSS.  If interested, you can read a [broader discussion on em units versus other units](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/).

**Using em units in FXML via expression binding**

Just setting a default font size gets you about 90% of the way to where you need to be, but is not necessarily a universal fix as some layout units might be specified not using em units.  Most of the time this isn't really an issue, but if it is in your case, you could also apply a mechanism described in an [Oracle developer mailing list post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-May/007738.html), which appears to work, though is a little clunky.

How about using an expression binding.

For 35em x 25em you could write:

```
prefWidth="${35*u.em}" prefHeight="${25*u.em}"
```

It's not 100% concise, but perhaps passable.

These kind of sizing expressions work in scene builder 1.1, which is nice.

---

Here is an example using a Rectangle to store the width and height modifiers for the fxml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<fx:define>
  <Rectangle fx:id="s" width="13" height="13"/>
</fx:define>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="${22 * s.width}" prefWidth="${14 * s.height}">
  <children>
    <Button layoutX="${4 * s.width}" layoutY="${ 5 * s.height}" prefWidth="${6 * s.width}" text="Top" />
    <Button layoutX="${4 * s.width}" layoutY="${10 * s.height}" prefWidth="${6 * s.width}" text="Middle" />
    <Button layoutX="${4 * s.width}" layoutY="${15 * s.height}" prefWidth="${6 * s.width}" text="Bottom" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
</StackPane>
```

---

Or instead, you can create your own unit class and use it in your sizing expressions, for example:

```
package org.jewelsea.measure;

public class Measurement {
  private double em;
  public  void   setEm(double em) { this.em = em; }
  public  double getEm()          { return em; }
}

. . .

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import org.jewelsea.measure.Measurement?>
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element .?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <fx:define>
    <Measurement fx:id="u" em="26.0" />
  </fx:define>
  <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="${22*u.em}" prefWidth="${14*u.em}">
    <children>
      <Button layoutX="${4*u.em}" layoutY="${ 5*u.em}" prefWidth="${6*u.em}" text="Top" />
      <Button layoutX="${4*u.em}" layoutY="${10*u.em}" prefWidth="${6*u.em}" text="Middle" />
      <Button layoutX="${4*u.em}" layoutY="${15*u.em}" prefWidth="${6*u.em}" text="Bottom" />
    </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: I don't want to bind _to_ the font size, I want to actually have the font change itself. Isn't this doing the opposite? Either way, I'm going to upvote this because I'll definitely use it in the future. I didn't even know this was possible :).

Comment: Please edit your question to explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added an extra sentence. Now that I read it, I can see how you interpreted the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: You are a JavaFX god, JewelSea. I've already used this answer for a completely unrelated problem. Since you've helped me so much on this project, I'm going to go ahead and put you in the credits. Now if I can get the font resizing working, it should allow everybody to see your name clearly on the splash screen :D. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 7):

There is a simplest and proper method to bind font size with the container size, in order to make it in a responsive font scale effect.

The `bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: "` is a good alternative but when you resize the windows it seems to be very slow and I think is not the proper way to resolve the problem.

You can declare FontProperty and bind this FontProperty to the Component (Label, Text, etc.) and finally create an event to bind the size with the FontProperty size according with our design:

```
private Label textTracking = new Label();
private ObjectProperty<Font> fontTracking = new SimpleObjectProperty<Font>(Font.getDefault());
```

Then in constructor or some init method you can bind the font property of our object with our dynamic font:

```
textTracking.fontProperty().bind(fontTracking);
```

Finally, you need to bind the wrapper container change size with the dynamic font size:

```
    widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldWidth, Number newWidth)
        {
            fontTracking.set(Font.font(newWidth.doubleValue() / 4));
        }
    });
```

With this solution the dynamic font adjustment is very flow and fast, even more than `bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: "` method.

Comment: It might be easier to do
`ObjectExpression<Font> fontTracking = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> Font.font(getWidth() / 4), widthProperty())` and then 
`textTracking.fontProperty().bind(fontTracking)`.

Comment: I think this is a better sol'n than mine.  I just had another upvote 7 years later and came to see why.  I know mine is a slower method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it this way:

1. in the CSS and FXML files, I defined all font sizes in a relative way, using only "em" instead of "%" or "px"
2. in the controller of the main window, I bound a double value within a style property of the main pane to some scene size property (e.g. a rough approximation of its diagonal length)

It works because the style that is set to the main pane will affect as a modifier all the nodes that are already defined in the FXML. The nodes that already have a style class are also impacted as the new style comes as an additional top layer of styling in the cascading style sheets.

The main advantage of this solution is to handle in a single place the font size zoom factor. Thus you don't have to find every node that has a Font property to make it working.

Sample files:

**styles.css**

```
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 1.1em;
}

.title {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

**main.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<BorderPane style="-fx-background-color: #fff;"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        prefWidth="1280.0" prefHeight="720.0"
        fx:controller="controllers.MainController">
    <top>
        <Label text="Application title" styleClass="title"/>
    </top>
    <center>
        <Label text="Lorem ipsum"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**MainController.java**

```
package controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class MainController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private BorderPane mainPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        initializeFontSizeManager();
    }

    private void initializeFontSizeManager() {
        // Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246211/javafx-how-to-get-stage-from-controller-during-initialization
        mainPane.sceneProperty().addListener((observableScene, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            // We need a scene to work on
            if (oldScene == null && newScene != null) {
                DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
                fontSize.bind(newScene.widthProperty().add(newScene.heightProperty())
                    .divide(1280 + 720) // I know, it's a very rough approximation :)
                    .multiply(100)); // get a suitable value to put before the '%' symbol in the style
                mainPane.styleProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize.asString("%.0f")).concat("%;"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question
but since 19-ea+9 you may use like

```
private DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10);
node.styleProperty().bind(fontSize.map(size -> "-fx-font-size: "+size+";-fx-base: rgb(0,0,255);"));
```