# Is it possible to use arithmetic expression in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I hoped for a feature that would allow me to work with numbers inside the FXML. For example, tried to define the height of one element to be equal to a constant and the height of the second element to be equal to the same constant multiplied by 2 (i.e. `constant * 2`). Is it possible to do it in FXML at all or do I need to do this part of view build-up inside the controller (which I would like to avoid)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<?import java.lang.Double?>

...

<fx:define>
    <Double fx:id="xHeight" fx:value="100" />
</fx:define>

...

<Label fx:id="lblElementOne" prefHeight="$xHeight" />
<Label fx:id="lblElementTwo" prefHeight="${xHeight * 2}" />
```

Comment: Is it working every time, or only when a binding is possible? I wanted to define coordinates for Polygon that way `<Double fx:value="${height / 2}"/>` and got an exception.

Comment: @RadosławŁazarz What exception is it?

Comment: A `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$width"`. On the other hand it works perfectly for `<Button text="${width * 2}" />`, so it is a problem with `Double` mostly. And it is the Polygon shape I hoped to define in smart way...

Answer (score 4):

**Use an Expression Binding**

You can use an [expression binding.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding)

```
<TextField fx:id="textField" prefWidth="40"/>
<Label prefWidth="${textField.prefWidth * 2}"/>
```

**On Constant Definition in FXML**

You could access a [constant defined in FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements) or an [FXML definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements).

There is an example of the use of such an approach in the answer to:

- [Bind Font Size in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23706030/1155209)

See the section in that answer titled: "Using em units in FXML via expression binding".

**On Constant Definition in CSS**

> BTW, is it possible to define constants in CSS? I thought the OP meant a constant inside FXML, but mentioned CSS.

I assumed a constant in FXML too until I re-read the question where it says "defined i.e. inside a CSS".  And, yes you can't really define a constant in JavaFX CSS, the closest thing might be a [looked-up-color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor), but that is pretty specific and a little different.  If you pass the CSS through a pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_), those systems allow the definition of constants (which LESS confusingly calls variables :-).  However, you can't directly access that kind of information through FXML.

Comment: +one you beat me by 15 seconds ;)

Comment: BTW, is it possible to define constants in CSS? I thought the OP meant a constant inside FXML, but mentioned CSS by mistake.

Comment: The CSS mention was my mistake, just as @Eng.Fouad assumed. Although I started wondering whether defining constants there would be possible, it is nice to know that not. ;]