# FXML arithmetic in prefHeight attribute to auto rescale on window resize?

Tags: javafx, scale, fxml

I want to set the prefHeight of an AnchorPane to 4 times the height of a GridPane. I have read in another post that this should be possible, at least for other elements:

[Is it possible to use arithmetic expression in FXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284004/is-it-possible-to-use-arithmetic-expression-in-fxml)

I am able to reference the height of the GridPane alone by itself fine like so:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="imagesAnchorPane" prefHeight="${buttonsGridPane.height}" minHeight="250.0" prefWidth="135.0">
```

but once I try to use  `prefHeight="${buttonsGridPane.height * 4}"` the `* 4` is highlighted red and the mouseover IntelliJ displays the error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'height * 4' with references to
> javafx.scene.layout.Region private
> javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty prefHeight

[image]

Same issue using 4 or 4.0 for all of the steps I have tried.

In an effort to more closely follow the proposed solutions in the linked post I also tried defining a double with the same arithmetic as to use it directly for the prefHeight but this will not even recognise the height reference alone, instead erroring with

> Invalid value: Unable to coerce to java.lang.Double

[image]

I am able to define it as a String, but when I then try to then multiple that String by 4 I receive the same error about unable to coerce to double:

```
  <fx:define>
    <String fx:id="xHeight" fx:value="${buttonsGridPane.height}"/>
    <Double fx:id="yHeight" fx:value="${xHeight * 4}"/>
  </fx:define>
```

I also have a method that will change the value, which I can call with onMouseClicked, but I have not been able to find a way to use it for an attribute as I expect this is not allowed:

```
    private void fixScale(){
    imagesAnchorPane.setPrefHeight(buttonsGridPane.getHeight() * 4);
}
```

For reference this is all in an effort to make it so that the AnchorPane, which is holding a GridPane of images will scale with the rest of the program when the window is resized as it is not. Although this AnchorPane may become a Java object, right now it has been implemented using SceneBuilder and opening tags of the FXML code is the following:

```
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.503708281829419" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="45.0" prefHeight="265.0" prefWidth="324.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                            <items>
                                                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: #bbc4c4; -fx-border-color: #323636; -fx-border-insets: 3; -fx-border-radius: 3; -fx-border-width: 2;">
                                       <children>
                                          <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" layoutX="-20.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="265.0" prefWidth="160.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                            <content>
                                              <AnchorPane fx:id="imagesAnchorPane" minHeight="250.0" onMouseClicked="#fixScale" prefWidth="135.0">
                                                   <children>
                                                      <GridPane prefHeight="574.0" prefWidth="135.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
```

And this is the current structure from the top level AnchorPane down to the imagesGridPane:

[image]

Comment: From the looks of your layout structure, I would recommend you spend more time learning about the layout nodes. I just can't imagine the use-case for all of those nested `SplitPanes`.

Comment: Does it run? This just sounds like IntelliJ not understanding expression binding.

Comment: @Sedrick I will look more at layout structure but do you think reducing the number of splitpanes will resolve the issue with the contents of a scrollpane not scaling when the window resizes or is there some other issue?

Comment: @James_D it does not run with the expression, the error output is here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sCF6sx9sZ8/ It should though, right?

Comment: Post your complete FXML. I can have a look.

Comment: In other words, please create and then post a [mre] demonstrating the problem.