# JavaFX change stage size from outside the constructor

Tags: java, javafx, resize, stage

I have something like

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        MyController controller = new MyController(model);
        MyView view = new MyView(model, controller);
        Scene scene = new Scene(view);

        stage.setTitle("MyTitle");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
        view.requestFocus();
    }

    public void changeStageSize(int width, int height) {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What do I have to write into my changeStageSize void to change my *stage* size?

Comment: It does not matter, since the `changeStageSize` isn't used anywhere...

Comment: I use it in the MyView class. Didn't post it, because nothing special is going on there.

Comment: Two problems: #1: your `Application` does not hold a reference to the `Stage`, #2: your `MyView` class doesn't hold a reference to the `Application`. What you could do: #1: pass the reference of the `Stage` to the controller, #2: in the controller get the `Stage` using any nodes added to the scene-graph by: `(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow()`. Then write the resizing method there. You can find an example for both cases in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246211/javafx-how-to-get-stage-from-controller-during-initialization). Then: `stage.setWidth`, `stage.setHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Resize");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        changeStageSize(primaryStage, 800, 500);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane(btn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void changeStageSize(Window stage, int width, int height) {
    stage.setWidth(width);
    stage.setHeight(height);
}
```

Just set the `width` and `height` of the `Window`. You could use a field instead of passing the `stage` parameter. If you don't do this IMHO the method should be made static, since no instance members of your application class are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `MyView` instance is the root of the scene, *from within `MyView`* you can just do

```
Window win = getScene().getWindow();
win.setWidth(...);
win.setHeight(...);
```

There is no need to delegate this method back to the `Application` subclass (and you really don't want `MyView` to have a dependency on that anyway.