# Set on Close Request method on a window using Scene builder

Tags: java, javafx-8

Since I can't use Scene builder to set this method

I'm trying to get the Window of the scene that is now displayed and set the method

```
public class MainController {
@FXML
    private Button Settings;
    public void initialize() {
     
    Window w =Settings.getScene().getWindow();

    w.setOnCloseRequest(ac->{

            System.out.println("Done");
        });
   }
}
```

Then I  have noticed that w = null ... and the get Scene method returns null too..

so 1) is there any way to make this with Scene builder without using (initialize way)
2) how can i fix the code above so i can use the window ?

Comment: I recommend reading the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247005/6395627) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30910015/6395627) and choose which solution best fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use getScene() in initialize method since you will get null. The root element is still not placed on the scene when initialize method is called for the controller.

Try this:

```
ChangeListener<Window> windowListener = new ChangeListener<>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue obs, Window oldVal, Window newVal) {
        if (newVal != null) {
            setting.getScene().getWindow().setOnCloseRequest(eh -> System.out.println("Done"));
            setting.getScene().windowProperty().removeListener(this);
        }
    }
};

ChangeListener<Scene> sceneListener = new ChangeListener<>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue obs, Scene oldVal, Scene newVal) {
        if (newVal != null) {
            newVal.windowProperty().addListener(windowListener);
            setting.sceneProperty().removeListener(this);
        }
    }
};

setting.sceneProperty().addListener(sceneListener);
```

In order to avoid unused listeners, I added a listener removal after setOnCloseRequest is set.

Comment: Ok newVal !=null now but the getWindow returns null .... still not working

Comment: ```
Settings.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (newVal != null) {
                newVal.windowProperty().addListener((obs2,last,now)->{
                    if(now!=null)
                        now.setOnCloseRequest(ac->{
                            System.out.println("Done");

                        });
                    else
                        System.out.println("Null");
                        }

                );
            }
        });
```
I used the same idea to check if the Window is null or not.... it Works perfectly !

Comment: The listener approach shown by @Wissam is the proper way to be notified of when the `Window` is no longer null. Adding a button which, _when manually pressed by the end user(!!!)_, adds a handler to the host window is not user friendly.

Comment: @Slaw Right  ... so i can't use  Oboe's code ....doesn't help me to set the method

Comment: @Slaw, you are right. The listener was my initial answer. My mistake for the wrong update... Guess is sunday night ;). I'll undo the answer back to my initial answer.

Comment: @Slaw, since you will use the listeners only once, I would remove them after they are used. I updated the code to include that.